# How to set relation between two objects without fetch them

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two Entities: `Project` and `Production`

Every `Project` has many `Productions`. So the relation of project is `toMany`

I'm getting all `Projects` and all `Productions` with two network request. I'm saving every project to the `CoreData`. It's around 100k projects and take me about 40 secs, Thats OK.

Getting around 100k Productions and saving to CoreData take me 50 secs. Thats OK too. But I didn't set relations yet.

So I'm setting a loop on all projects that fetched with `NSFetchRequest` for setting relation on prepare production.

```
for project in Project.getAll() {
    project.addToProductions(Produciton.getProductionById(project.producionId))
}
```

This loop takes a lot of time and CPU. something around 10 minutes with getting `CPU Over Budget x2` on Profiling.

If there is a way to set relation without getting productions that would be helpful Or I have switch `CoreData` to `SQLite` or `Realm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create both entity objects simultaneously and use a cache for the `Project` objects.

- Enable inverse relationship in the model.
- Get both `Project` and `Production` data from the network.
- Create an `NSCache`.
- Start creating CoreData `Production` objects.
- Look if there is a corresponding `Project` object in the cache.
- If there is one set the `project` property to the `Project` object.
- If there is none create a CoreData `Project` object from the corresponding project data and put it in the cache.

Comment: Inverse is enabled but `NSCache` on which object? you mean caching on an array of projects?

Comment: For example a suitable string key which can be build from the production item and a `Project` value `[String:Project]`

Comment: I tried loading all Projects and Production to memory and loop on them and setting relations. but filtering is expensive process. I don't think that caching would be faster. right?

Comment: You don't *filter* the data. `NSCache` is based on a hash table and key value pairs like a dictionary

Comment: Caching was a mazing idea! thanks. I just checked the cache. I should try simultaneously connection to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a completion block and call this second function to end of the completion.

Comment: It doesn't make any improvement in timing.